# Unicode -- missing arrows

Tags: unicode, language-agnostic

I'm currently working with arrows in unicode.

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_by_Unicode_plane), these five arrows are defined:

```
↳ ↲ ↱ ↰ ↴
```

However, three arrows are missing :

- leftwards, tip downwards
- leftwards, tip upwards
- rightwards, tip upwards

How can i find, or, if inexistant, replace them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are provided in the [Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Arrows) table:

```
 ⬎ ⬏ ⬐ ⬑
```